# Add to cart session not creating properly

Tags: php, session

I have created an add to cart functionality I am not pretty sure if I have developed perfectly or not.

when I am trying to add new session cart item it is not setting up for me the quantity, and `pid` is inserting properly,  but the other two options I am unable to store though like if i try to create a variable `$_SESSION['cart']['pid']`.

it is working fine but when I try to add another session variable `$_SESSION['cart']['option1']` it is not working

```
if(isset($_POST['cart'])) {
    $pid  = $_POST['product_id'];
    $qty  = $_POST['qty'];
    $opt1 = $_POST['opt1'];
    $opt2 = $_POST['opt2'];

    if(isset($_SESSION['cart']['pid'][$pid])) {
        $_SESSION['cart']['pid'][$pid]++;
        $_SESSION['cart']['opt1'][$pid] = $opt1;
        $_SESSION['cart']['opt2'][$pid] = $opt2;
        if($qty > 1) {
            $_SESSION['cart']['pid'][$pid] = $qty;
        }
    } else {
        $_SESSION['cart']['pid'][$pid] = 1;
        if($qty > 1) {
            $_SESSION['cart']['pid'][$pid] = $qty;
        }
    }
}

<form method="POST" action="result.php">
     <input type="text" name="product_id" placeholder="Product Id" />
     <input type="text" name="qty" placeholder="Quantity" />
     <input type="text" name="opt1" placeholder="A" />
     <input type="text" name="opt2" placeholder="b" />
     <input type="submit" name="cart" value="Add To Cart" />
</form>
```

Please let me know if I am on the right track and also the add to cart function is properly developed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confused, specially when you add an already-stored-in-session product:

When you already have the product_id in your cart, you write:

```
$_SESSION['cart']['pid'][$pid]++;
```

...so you lost the product_id from your pid session index.

Maybe you should just add the quantity in another pid -> variable ... instead of changing the pid value.

```
if(isset($_POST['cart'])) {
    $pid  = $_POST['product_id'];
    $qty  = $_POST['qty'];
    $opt1 = $_POST['opt1'];
    $opt2 = $_POST['opt2'];

    // Create the prodcut_id array if it does not exist
    if(!isset($_SESSION['cart']['pid'][$pid])) {
        $_SESSION['cart']['pid'][$pid] = array();
    }

    // Is the same item already stored? (same opt1 and opt2)
    $sameItem = false;

    if (!empty($_SESSION['cart']['pid'][$pid])) {
        foreach ($_SESSION['cart']['pid'][$pid] as $key => $product) {
             // Same options item?
             if ($product['opt1'] == $opt1 && 
                 $product['opt2'] == $opt2) {
                  $sameItem = $key;
             }
        }
    }

    if ($sameItem !== false) {
        // Change the quantity
        $_SESSION['cart']['pid'][$pid][$sameItem]['qty'] += $qty;
    } else {
        // Store the item as new array key
        array_push($_SESSION['cart']['pid'][$pid], 
               array('qty' => $qty, 'opt1' => $opt1, 'opt2' => $opt2);
    }

}
```

By the way, are you using session_start() properly?

Comment: Awesome thanks a lot but have a confusion about $sameitem and foreach loop will you be able to explain how you did this

Comment: I use $sameItem as a flag to detect if any of same-product_id is already stored in the cart. If so, I just increase the quantity, if not then I add the item as a new type of product. Think on a **t-shirt**: if you add (another) _red t-shirt_ to your cart, you should increase the quantity instead of adding another new item to your cart. If the t-shirt is blue (remember you have a red t-shirt in your cart), you should display it in your cart as another item so do not increase the quantity.